# ExoPlayer, how to load bigger parts of remote audio files

Tags: android, audio-streaming, exoplayer

I'm using ExoPlayer 2 to play remote tracks. By default the player loads tracks piece by piece (i.e. about 20 seconds, then other 20 seconds while the track is playing).

Since tracks are loaded from a remote server, it happens that if connection goes down, the player is not able to load anymore. Is there a way to say to ExoPlayer to load bigger parts of the audio file (also the full track at once)?

I tried to see around `ExtractorMediaSource`, `DataSource.Factory` and `DefaultExtractorsFactory` but I've found nothing to solve my problem.

```
val audioSource = ExtractorMediaSource(
        Uri.parse(videoUrl),
        mDataSourceFactory,    // DataSource.Factory
        mExtractor,    // DefaultExtractorsFactory
        null,
        null
)

mExoPlayer.prepare(audioSource)
mExoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
```

(it is Kotlin, but it seems to be understandable also by Java programmers)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've found the solution. Since I'm not finding other related questions, I'll answer to my question (I hope someone will need it in the future):

The right object to configure is the `LoadControl` passed to the `ExoPlayerFactory` when creating the `ExoPlayer` object:

Original answer (deprecated):

```
val loadControl = DefaultLoadControl(
            DefaultAllocator(true, C.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE),
            5 * 60 * 1000, // this is it!
            10 * 60 * 1000,
            DefaultLoadControl.DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_MS.toLong(),
            DefaultLoadControl.DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_AFTER_REBUFFER_MS.toLong()
)
exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl)
```

The updated answer:

```
val bandwidthMeter = DefaultBandwidthMeter.Builder(context).build()
val trackSelectionFactory = AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory()
val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(trackSelectionFactory)

val loadControl = DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
        .setAllocator(DefaultAllocator(true, C.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE))
        .setBufferDurationsMs(
            5 * 60 * 1000, // this is it!
            10 * 60 * 1000,
            DefaultLoadControl.DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_MS,
            DefaultLoadControl.DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_AFTER_REBUFFER_MS
        )
        .setTargetBufferBytes(DefaultLoadControl.DEFAULT_TARGET_BUFFER_BYTES)
        .setPrioritizeTimeOverSizeThresholds(DefaultLoadControl.DEFAULT_PRIORITIZE_TIME_OVER_SIZE_THRESHOLDS)
        .createDefaultLoadControl()

exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
        context,
        DefaultRenderersFactory(context),
        trackSelector,
        loadControl,
        null,
        bandwidthMeter)
```

[The doc](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/DefaultLoadControl.html#DefaultLoadControl-com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultAllocator-int-int-long-long-) where it is explained.

Comment: `@deprecated Use {@link Builder} instead.`

Comment: I'm getting this error  ~> Cannot resolve method 'DefaultAllocator(boolean, int)'. Could anyone please tell workaround for this error. Thank you

Comment: Which version of ExoPlayer are you using? DefaultAllocator is available since 2.4.0

Answer (score 4):

Answer of @Massimo is correct but the way is deprecated

use something like this

```
DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
            .setBufferDurationsMs(
                DefaultLoadControl.DEFAULT_MIN_BUFFER_MS, 
                30_000, 
                DefaultLoadControl.DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_MS,
                DefaultLoadControl.DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_AFTER_REBUFFER_MS
            )
```

Comment: This needs `.createDefaultLoadControl()` at the end for the builder pattern to complete